# Python Set Intersection - Which objects are returned

Tags: python, set

I have a question which is not really clear in python documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection).

When using set.intersection the resulting set contains the objects from current set or from other? In the case that both objects have same value but are different objects in memory.

I am using this to compare a previous extraction taken from file with a new one coming from the internet. Both have some objects that are similar but I want to update the old ones.
Or maybe there is a simpler alternative to achieve this? It would me much easier if sets implemented `__getitem__`.

```
    oldApsExtract = set()
    if (os.path.isfile("Apartments.json")):
        with open('Apartments.json', mode='r') as f:
            oldApsExtract = set(jsonpickle.decode(f.read()))
    newApsExtract = set(getNewExtract())

    updatedAps = oldApsExtract.intersection(newApsExtract)
    deletedAps = oldApsExtract.difference(newApsExtract)
    newAps = newApsExtract.difference(oldApsExtract)

    for ap in deletedAps:
        ap.mark_deleted()

    for ap in updatedAps:
        ap.update()

    saveAps = list(oldApsExtract) + list(newAps)
    with open('Apartments.json', mode='w') as f:
        f.write(jsonpickle.encode(saveAps))
```

Comment: "Both have some objects that are similar but **I want to update the old ones**" - if your objects are mutable, you probably can't put them in a set at all. If you can, you're probably breaking the rule that hashable objects can't be mutable in ways that affect `==` comparisons. Sets really aren't designed for mutable contents.

Comment: Why do you need `__getitem__`? If that's really what you want, you could do `for thing in set1: if thing in set2: do_whatever(thing)`.

Comment: @user2357112 the update I am making does not affect the equality criteria and also does not affect the hash for the objects

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You are right. I just wanted to take advantage of the built in methods because they are usually more optimized.

Comment: It would be bad practice to count on implementation-specific behavior which is what your question asks for. You probably shouldn't be creating mutable but hash-invariant objects anyway. There are better approaches.

Comment: If you find your approach would be easier if only the language was extended, it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Non-equal objects can still be [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). If their equivalence is more important than their strict equality and must always hold, then it makes sense to redefine `__hash__` and `__eq__` appropriately. As for mutability, see the concept of "interior mutability".

Answer (score 7):

What objects are used varies, if the sets are the same size the intersecting elements from b, if b has more elements then the objects from a are returned:

```
i = "$foobar" * 100
j = "$foob" * 100
l  = "$foobar" * 100
k = "$foob" * 100
print(id(i), id(j))
print(id(l), id(k))
a = {i, j}
b = {k, l, 3}
inter = a.intersection(b)
for ele in inter:
    print(id(ele))
```

Output:

```
35510304 35432016
35459968 35454928
35510304
35432016
```

Now when they are the same size:

```
i = "$foobar" * 100
j = "$foob" * 100
l  = "$foobar" * 100
k = "$foob" * 100
print(id(i), id(j))
print(id(l), id(k))
a = {i, j}
b = {k, l}
inter = a.intersection(b)
for ele in inter:
    print(id(ele))
```

Output:

```
35910288 35859984
35918160 35704816
35704816
35918160
```

There relevant part of the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1294). The line `if (PySet_GET_SIZE(other) > PySet_GET_SIZE(so))`, n the result of the comparison seems to decide which object to iterate over and what objects get used.

```
    if (PySet_GET_SIZE(other) > PySet_GET_SIZE(so)) {
        tmp = (PyObject *)so;
        so = (PySetObject *)other;
        other = tmp;
    }
     
    while (set_next((PySetObject *)other, &pos, &entry)) {
        key = entry->key;
        hash = entry->hash;
        rv = set_contains_entry(so, key, hash);
        if (rv < 0) {
            Py_DECREF(result);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (rv) {
            if (set_add_entry(result, key, hash)) {
                Py_DECREF(result);
                return NULL;
            }
```

If you pass an object that is not a set, then the same is not true and the length is irrelevant as the objects from the iterable are used:

```
it = PyObject_GetIter(other);
if (it == NULL) {
    Py_DECREF(result);
    return NULL;
}

while ((key = PyIter_Next(it)) != NULL) {
    hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
    if (hash == -1)
        goto error;
    rv = set_contains_entry(so, key, hash);
    if (rv < 0)
        goto error;
    if (rv) {
        if (set_add_entry(result, key, hash))
            goto error;
    }
    Py_DECREF(key);
```

When you pass an iterable, firstly it could be an iterator so you could not check the size without consuming and if you passed a list then the lookup would be `0(n)` so it makes sense to just iterate over the iterable passed in, in contrast if you have a set of `1000000` elements and one with `10`, it makes sense to check if the `10` are in the set if `1000000` as opposed to checking if any of `1000000` are in your set of `10` as the lookup should be `0(1)` on average so it mean a linear pass over 10 vs a linear pass over 1000000 elements.

If you look at the [wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), this is backed up:

> Average case  -> Intersection s&t O(min(len(s), len(t))
>
> Worst case -> O(len(s) * len(t))O(len(s) * len(t))
>
> *replace "min" with "max" if t is not a set*

So when we pass an iterable we should always get the objects from b:

```
i = "$foobar" * 100
j = "$foob" * 100
l  = "$foobar" * 100
k = "$foob" * 100
print(id(i), id(j))
print(id(l), id(k))
a = {i, j}
b = [k, l, 1,2,3]
inter = a.intersection(b)
for ele in inter:
    print(id(ele))
```

You get the objects from b:

```
20854128 20882896
20941072 20728768
20941072
20728768
```

If you really want to decide what objects you keep then do the iterating and lookups yourself keeping whichever you want.

Comment: Thanks. I would expect that the result would be more "expectable". It could be up to the programmer to choose which one to iterate over.

Comment: @husvar, I suppose if you are looking for the intersection it makes more sense to iterate over the smaller set, no point iterating over 10000 elements if the other set only has 10

Comment: @husvar What's iterated over and what's returned are completely independent things. When you find a match, you have both elements, so you can return either without incurring any extra time complexity.
You're right that it would be better to always return elements from the first set.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is instead use python dictionaries. Access is still O(1), elements are easy to access, and a simple loop such as follows can get the intersection feature:

```
 res=[]
 for item in dict1.keys():
  if dict2.has_key(item):
   res.append(item)
```

The advantage here is you have full control of what is going on, and can tweak it as you need to. For example, can also do things like:

```
if dict1.has_key(item):
 dict1[item]=updatedValue
```

Comment: Do not use `.has_key`; it's deprecated, and slower than pure syntax based containment checks. Replace `dict1.has_key(item)` with `item in dict1`, and it runs faster (and works equally well with all container types, not just `dict`). Similarly, don't iterate over `.keys()`; it's redundant in Py3, and wasteful in Py2 (where it creates a whole new `list` to contain all the keys); you can iterate the keys directly (no copies, no calls) with `for item in dict1:`

Comment: And of course, this is all pointless; you could do the exact same thing with `set`s anyway, so why are we bothering with `dict`, where you'd have to store a junk value with each key?

Comment: I used a dict since he mentioned something about a get_item method, and dicts allow you to do this in O(1) time.

Comment: `set`s have the same average case time for membership testing. I suppose you could allow someone to retrieve a non-equal-but-equal object by maintaining a `dict` that maps keys to themselves, but really, if you're in that position, you've almost certainly violated the mutability invariants that `set` members and `dict` keys are supposed to adhere to.

Comment: Oh originally this question requested for a fast way to get an item, and I interpreted this as meaning accessing any random item based on a key. I was not under the impression that sets have this ability.